# Get the values of a Observable<any> into an array in typescript

Tags: json, angular, typescript, observable

I'm trying to get the values from a post in typescript, I'm getting a Observable type variable from the post operation but I don't know how can I get the values within. Is there a way to do this?

Here is the code I have until now

```
TryLogin() {
    this.loggedUser.email = this.inputUsername;
    this.loggedUser.password = this.inputPass;
    const myObjStr = JSON.stringify(this.loggedUser)
    const response = this.http.post<any>(this.url, myObjStr,{headers: this.httpheaders});
  }
```

Comment: Subscribe to it? I'd strongly recommend reading https://angular.io/guide/http

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You'll need to subscribe to it. But before you do any of that, I suggest giving the angular documentation a read and get familiar with it.

https://angular.io/docs

```
TryLogin() {
    this.loggedUser.email = this.inputUsername;
    this.loggedUser.password = this.inputPass;
    const myObjStr = JSON.stringify(this.loggedUser)
    let userInfo;
    this.http.post<any>(this.url, myObjStr, { headers: this.httpheaders }).subscribe((response) => {
        // do something with your response here
        userInfo = response;
    });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Why not try to subscribe to the observable and assign the result to a response variable ?:

```
this.http.post<any>(this.url, myObjStr,{headers: this.httpheaders}).subscribe(
result => {
// assigned to a class property response for convenience.
 this.response = result;
} );
```

Take note that an Observable/Subject is something that Informs everything that 'subscribes' to it (subscribers), that a value inside of it has been changed.

Comment: This code is incorrect and doesn't do anything other than getting a value. You cannot return a value from a subscribe() like in your code. You'll need to assign the result to another var inside of your subscribe or just do something with the value you there.

Comment: The code has been corrected.